# Is it possible to remotely profile Azure Websites using DotTrace?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, dottrace

I have seen a few articles on using DotTrace with Azure Cloud Services, but not Azure Websites. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach works: http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/12/11/remote-profiling-web-applications-with-dottrace-performance/

You will have to install the NuGet package and enable it and then attach to a URL similar to http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/AgentService.asmx.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Web Apps, API Apps and WebJobs can now be remotely profiled directly from Visual Studio 2015 or through a the kudu dashboard / REST API

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-profiling-support-in-azure-app-service/

Comment: Thanks for this, most useful. Need to upgrade to VS2015